# Diagnosing why Flutter MaterialApp theme runtime change is slow on device only

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm wrapping a `SharedPreferences` service class in a provider class that implements `PreferencesProvider.of(context)`. It sets the theme as follows:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: PreferencesProvider.of(context).service.isDark,
      initialData: PreferencesProvider.of(context).service.isDark.value, //its an rxDart ValueObservable
      builder: (context, snapshot) => MaterialApp(
        theme: ThemeData(
          brightness: snapshot.data ? Brightness.dark : Brightness.light,
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
///etc etc etc
```

Widgets can change the theme simply with `PreferencesProvider.of(context).service.toggleIsDark()`. It works well, but it takes about 3 seconds of being frozen to change theme on my device. On the emulator, it happens instantly.

Any possible leads on debugging this would be great. I've tried using the Dart Observatory Timeline but I couldn't see anything helpful (I couldn't make much sense of it).

Comment: I was able to solve this specific problem. I was initializing some blocs on rebuild, I moved them outside the `MaterialApp` so that wouldn't happen on theme change. However I'd still like to know how I could have diagnosed it better.

Comment: I'm facing a similar issue, so I'd be interested in how to get to the root of this as well :)

Comment: @kazume can't offer much but have a look at your rebuilds and make sure you don't have anything expensive.

Comment: Hey @Lucas, please answer you question providing your code that solves this problem.

Answer (score 0):

This was happening because I was creating my BLoCs in the outermost build function. I moved creation to `main()` and passed in the created BLoCs which solved the problem. Don't create anything except widgets in build functions!